# Some NuxtJS images break upon reload

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js

In my website I have a series of images that serve as nuxt links to game pages:

```html
<template>
  <NuxtLink :to="game.pageName">
    <img :src="game.boxImage" :height="gamePanelHeight" class="elevation-4"
  /></NuxtLink>
</template>
```

Each of those links draws its properties from a content markup file like this:

```
index: 3
boxImage: gameImages/box_image.png
title: game title
pageName: games/whatever
```

And they're loaded into the page like so:

```html
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const games = await $content('games').sortBy('index', 'asc').fetch()
    return { games }
  },
}
</script>
```

Whenever I refresh this page. All of these images break until I navigate outside the page and come back. What's causing this issue and how do I fix it?

This is a static Nuxt application FYI. And it's being served through an AWS S3 bucket but I don't think that's what's causing this issue.

**EDIT:** Also the boxImage that's in gameImages/box_image.png is from the static folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncData` is not a hook that is triggered upon reaching an URL or using a reload (F5), it is only triggered during navigation.

If you want it to work even after a reload, use the `fetch()` hook.
More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch#options

---

##### Edit on how to write it with `fetch()`

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      games: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    this.games = await this.$content('games').sortBy('index', 'asc').fetch()
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post more information about how this should be setup? I'm having trouble using fetch to access $content.

Comment: @hipsterstomper69 I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Ok thank you it's working now. For some reason for about 10 minutes after making the change the images would still break. It looks like it would originally load the img url as "www.site.com/gameImages/blah.png" but after refresh it would change to "www.site.com/library/gameImages.blah.png" for some reason. After about 10 minutes it stopped doing this. Perhaps it has something to do with CloudFront invalidations?

Comment: @hipsterstomper69 yeah probably some kind of cache. Glad it works!